# How to flag posts using jQuery dialog widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My goal is for a user to click on a Flag link and have a dialog box popup for the user to enter in some text to explain the situation. I'm not exactly sure how I should set it up so that the flag link only pulls up the dialog box that is connected to the post being flagged. Here is what I have so far:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".flagDialog").dialog({ 
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 550      
             });

    $(".flag").click(function() {
        var target = $(this);
        $(".flagDialog").dialog( "open" );
        $(".flagDialog").dialog("widget").position({
           my: 'left top',
           at: 'left bottom',
           of: target
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     extract($row);

     <div class='flag'>Flag</div>
     <div class="flagDialog" title="Flag">
        <form action="flag.php" class="flagForm" method="post">
             <textarea name="flag_input" class="flagInput" rows="6" cols="55"><?php echo $username; ?></textarea>
         </form> 
     </div>
   }
```

Currently, when I click on any of the flag links all of the dialogs that have gone threw the while loop popup, which makes sense, I'm just not sure how I should go about differentiating them from each other and dealing with it on the jQuery side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You somehow have to give the flag somemore information about itself, the line where the flag-div is generated would than look something like this:

```
 <div class="flag" alt="<?php echo $row->ID; ?>">Flag</div>
```

You just store the information about the flag in the alt-Attribute of the div

In jQuery you than refer to the alt-Attribute like that:

```
$(".flag").click(function() {
    var alt = $(this).attr("alt"); //Do something with it.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify each "Flag" and dialog separately (via ID, class or other attribute)

OR

if your code HTML looks like in your example, you can use [next() selector](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$(".flag").click(function() { 
    $(this).next('div.flagDialog').dialog( "open" );
    $(this).next('div.flagDialog').dialog("widget").position({
       my: 'left top',
       at: 'left bottom',
       of: $(this)
    });
});
```